# How can I get matplotlib work correctly

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, nltk

Recently I am learning to using nltk on Windows 7. I installed Python2.7 and NumPy1.6.2 and matplotlib 1.3.0 for Python 2.7. But when I try to run the following code it just won't work(The first line works correctly):

```
from nltk.book import *
text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])
```

The code is from the book of *Natural Languages Processing with Python*. The error information is as followed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])
  File "D:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 456, in dispersion_plot
    dispersion_plot(self, words)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\draw\dispersion.py", line 27, in dispersion_plot
    raise ValueError('The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab).'
ValueError: The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab).See http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/
```

How can I get it work correctly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You clearly did not install `matplotlib` in a way that your python shell is able to find it.  From the information given, there is no way we can help you.

Comment: Well, I'll try to install it again. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: also check that all your paths are correct and you don't have more than one (conflicting) version of python installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use Python 2.7 or above, this answer is not for you. I got the same error messages with Python 2.7.

The [nltk book](http://nltk.org/book/ch01.html) assumes you are running Python 2.4 or 2.5. Try to install Python 2.5 and the [packages/libs](http://nltk.org/install.html) ***for Python 2.5*** as follows. As suggested by nltk, avoid 64-bit versions.

1. Install Python 2.5.4: www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.4/
2. Install Numpy-1.7.1:  sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.1
3. Install NLTK 2.0.4:   pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk
4. Install PyYAML 3.10:  pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML
5. Test installation: Start>Python25, then type import nltk
6. Install Matplotlib: www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib
7. >>> import matplotlib

Try the example again and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too，than I fount I should install the dependencies first.(I use python 2.7 64bit)

Here's a list of the programs you can install on windows:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

And you'll need the following dependencies: Requires numpy, dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, six

Answer (score 0):

Install matplotlib-1.1.0, not the latest version. The problem will be solved.

Comment: While this may help, it's much more useful to provide an answer as to _why_ this is a good tactic here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Python 2.7

```
from nltk.book import *
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])
```

TkAgg requires TkInter.
[Here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) is more about backends which matplotlib can use.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but perhaps this helps anybody new to Python (maybe their first experience with the language is through the NLTK book?).

I got the same error and realized I just had to install the libraries.

First of all, exit the python interpreter with `exit()` command if you are still at the `>>>` prompt. Then run `pip install matplotlib`, that should trigger the download of the package and its dependencies (even NumPy, which is recommended in the NLTK install instructions page, if you don't have it).

Once it finishes, fire up the python interpreter again (with `python` or `idle`, whatever command you used to start it before), run `from nltk.book import *` again, wait for the list to finish, and try the `text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])` command again. It should work now!

Note: Pip is the usually recommended Python package installer, you can use it to easily install packages from internet or from local .whl ("wheel") files.